# What are some open problems in classical electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, magnetostatics

I am about to finish reading 'Introduction to Electrodynamics' by David Griffiths. Throughout the textbook, Griffiths makes frequent references to current literature (mostly articles from American Journal of Physics). So, I concluded that even though the theory of electrodynamics has a well established foundation, there might be some interesting "side problems" which are still open, hence the question.

Comment: The issue I quote Griffiths talking about [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/150501/59406) might be an example, but people with more expertise may be able to offer more.

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65410/2451

Comment: Americal Journal of Physics used to be called "American Physics Teacher". A lot of the articles are about teaching issues or clever little problems based on basic material.

Comment: @Qmechamic, I am more interested in what hft describes as "clever little problems based on basic material". I am not looking for a discussion on "problems" that are resolved by the corresponding quantum theory. That is why I mentioned "side problems".